# CouchDB from-source-code installation location on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb

I want to access the `plugins` folder in `CouchDB` installation directory but can't find it anywhere. Does anyone know where is it?

Comment: Did you install CouchDB from .deb files, or from source?

Comment: I installed from source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the CouchDB plugins directory location on the  `/usr/local/etc/couchdb/default.ini` configuration file.

```
plugin_dir = /usr/local/lib/couchdb/plugins
```

You can access the CouchDB plugins directory using following command, There you can find couchDB related plugins & erlang related plugins

**Note :** CouchDB Written in Erlang programming language.

```
cd /usr/local/lib/couchdb/plugins && ll

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 19 14:52 bin/  
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep  3  2016 erlang/
```